# Notice: Undefined offset 5584 in systom.log

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing "Notice: Undefined offset 5584" systom.log error for below code :

```
<?php $s_qty = 0; ?>

<tr id="item<?php echo $item->getId(); ?>">

<?php
$session_flag = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['bluedartItemsQty'])) {
    $qtyArr = $_SESSION['bluedartItemsQty'];

    $s_qty = abs($qtyArr[$item->getId()]); // Error in this line 
    $session_flag = 1;
    $sess_qty += $s_qty;
}
?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php if($s_qty > 0) { echo $s_qty; } else { echo $_qty; }  ?>" />
```

I added below code in begining , but it did't worked for me.

```
if( !isset($s_qty)) $s_qty = '' ;
```

Comment: here is full code : https://pastebin.com/pZd5ANMU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add a check at the given line ...

```
$session_flag = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['bluedartItemsQty'])) {
    $qtyArr = $_SESSION['bluedartItemsQty'];

    if (isset($qtyArr[$item->getId()])) { # added
        $s_qty = abs($qtyArr[$item->getId()]); // Error in this line 
        $session_flag = 1;
        $sess_qty += $s_qty;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , i added your code & checked , there is no log errors and than again i removed your code and checked with old code, still there was no errors :) i am not getting what actually happend, but its working fine......

Comment: Thx. I'd keep the line just to prevent further errros :)